# How to get the size of ip_sf_socklist

Tags: c, linux, kernel, sizeof, igmp

In my code I'm trying to get the size of ip_sf_socklist. The only problem is, that this structure is defined (in igmp.h) after:

```
#ifdef __KERNEL__
```

So in userspace, I can't see that structure. I could include the header in form /usr/src/linux-headers-x.x.xx but that wouldn't be elegant and could cause trouble if I move to a higher kernel. If I forget to change the header included in such case, that would cause some discrepancy.

Is there an easier way to get the sizeof that structure, something diffirent than having a symbolic link pointing to the latest header (which would be updated in makefile)?

Comment: If this structure is used only internally inside the kernel, how can you access it from userspace in the first place?

Comment: I don't use it. I need it's size to calculate a proper value for /proc/sys/net/core/optmem_max